# Serial port forwarding over TCP/IP (linux server)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcpip, port-forwarding, serial

I am looking for a way to use a remote serial port on a linux machine over LAN. The machine is running ubuntu 10.04 and I have a arduino board connected to it, that I would like to be able to reprogram or listen/talk to serial output of it over LAN.

It would be great if the client software would be platform indepented but linux only client would be ok too.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

There are some programs like that for windows: 
http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html
http://www.serial-port-communication.com/serial-over-tcpip/ (this appears to have a linux version to, but its not open source...)

And finally actually wikipedia has some useful notes and references:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector

**UPDATE2: Most interesting candidate:**
http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try remserial http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/ (though that might well not work) or ser2net (in universe) + a client. I'd personally be a bit nervous about flashing it over it though.

Answer (score 3):

You could SSH to the machine having the connection to the arduino board, and access the serial port through `minicom` or whatever. I am not sure how you would forward it though, not sure if it is possible.

Comment: +1 this is what I do to manage my remote network devices: I have a 1U rack-mounted Intel Atom "server" as my management workstation running Debian with no X, but with a couple of PCI serial cards in it.

Answer (score 2):

screen does a very good job of this. Ssh into the remote box and `screen /dev/ttyWhatever baudrate`

Comment: How do you set data bits, stop bits, parity, and flow control?