# Debian as TCP-Server for Serial Port redirecting

Tags: tcp, serial, tty

I want to start a tcp listener on debian. One client should be able to connect and should get inputs of serial port in the tcp connection. And when the client sends data through the tcp socket the data should be sent into the serial port.

I found other solutions where the linux server connects to another server redirects the serial port ([Other Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/154573/serial-port-forwarding-over-tcp-ip-linux-server)).

But I want that my machine is a tcp server.

Is there a built-in tool in debian that helps me doing this?

Comment: Your question looks exactly the same as that one, and its accepted answer looks like it will solve your problem. Exactly what is different about your question?

Comment: I dont want that the server connects to someone, i want that he waits for incoming connections. He should listen on a port and redirect any data coming from clients to the serial port.

Comment: It does both. Did you not read the answers given there?